# Self-type annotation hinders instantiation of inner class. Why?

Tags: class, scala, abstract, traits, self-type

Given the abstract definitions of the `Outer` class and its `Inner` class I would like to instantiate the concrete `Inner1` class defined within `Outer1` trait.

```
abstract class Outer {
  type Inner_Tp <: Inner;
  abstract class Inner {
    self: Inner_Tp =>
  }
}

trait Outer1 {
  self: Outer =>
  protected class Inner1 extends Inner {
    self: Inner_Tp =>
  }
  def Inner1() = new Inner1()
}
```

The Scala compiler prematurely terminates the compilation giving me the following error message: "error: class Inner1 cannot be instantiated because it does not conform to its self-type Outer1.this.Inner1 with Outer1.this.Inner_Tp". **Why?**

After all the `Inner1` class is defined within an abstract context being its `Outer1` trait. I would like to postpone the definition of `type Inner_Tp` until the trait gets mixed into some concrete class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For `Inner1`, the self-type says that it will always be instantiated together with the abstract type `Inner_Tp`. That's a promise that is not fulfilled at the instantiation point: the type is only `Inner1` instead of `Inner1 with Inner_Tp`.

If you need to delay the definition of `Inner_Tp`, you also need to delay the creation of any instances that have it as a self-type. That is absolutely necessary, since you cannot produce a value of a type that you don't know yet. So better leave the method abstract. You may refine the abstract type as well:

```
trait Outer1 extends Outer {
   type Inner_Tp <: Inner1
   protected class Inner1 extends Inner

   def Inner1(): Inner_Tp
}
```

I'm not sure what you are after, but you may not need the self-types at all (I left them out for brevity already).

Answer (score 1):

Because the `self: Inner_Tp` tells that no subtype of `Inner` will be allowed to be instanciated unless it is a subtype of `Inner_Tp` too.

Rewriting `self => Inner_Tp` in `Inner1` just restates the constraint, it does not satisfy it. To get a similar idea, when you have a descendant of an abstract class, if it does not implement the abstract method, you must write again that it is abstract. And you cannot instanciate. Same here, you restated that `Inner_Tp` is required, you did not make `Inner_Tp` available.

As long as `Inner_Tp` is an abstract type, you will not be able to mix it in, and so you will not be able to write `new Inner1`. You should probably introduce an abstract method that create Inners.

Comment: Thx guys, I've accepted Iulian Dragos response as the answer, altough you explain it equally well. +1 for your response.

Comment: That's fine, Iulian's SO reputation clearly does not reflect his mastery of scala, so he must be given lot of points :)